clothes disappeared in blender and I can't get them back
I'm creating a top using a mesh model, and clicked '3D view full' out of curiosity, and then when I returned to the default window, the clothes were seemingly invisible. The texture and 'shape' of the clothes is still there on the body, and I thought maybe I had just lost the clothes, but when I open the render the clothes are there! (top left of screen). I'm very new to blender so I really don't know what I've done. I checked the viewport display and the alpha is 1. 


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

try to this : obejct mode -> alt + h (unhide)

@Jakemoyo I've just added the link for the file below the image

@novacrown that doesn't work :(

In the Viewport Shading > Color settings for the Solid mode there is Texture enabled. This can be used to preview certain textures on the objects rather than the usual grey color or MatCap.

As shown in the other answer by @3fingeredfrog you can go back to normal by switching the Solid mode Color settings and then use the other shading modes to see the textures/materials. But I just want to explain to you what is happening there and why you see what you see:
The Solid mode set to Texture - other than the Material Preview or Rendered mode - does not show all textures and their combinations/mixing on the model, but only a single image texture (no procedural textures), precisely the one which is the currently active selected image texture in the material or which was the last image texture selected before some other non-texture node was selected. A more detailed explanation how this works you'll find in my answer here: Texture is appearing transparent
In your case, all materials on the object have this mess of a nodetree where everything is put on top of each other and you cannot see the individual Image Texture nodes. Apart from that, all nodes are selected with the Material Output being the active object:

If I now separate the nodes a bit so that you can see them better and then actively select the Image Texture node with the "DiffuseMap.003" you will see there is something different now. Selecting "BaseTexture.003" will switch back to the underwear/skin texture.

If you do this for all three materials on the object, it will look like the following picture. Although there is now the top again covering the bra, but this still looks incorrect as some parts of the body are now transparent.
This is because as mentioned in the beginning and explained in the other answer, this Texture shading mode only shows a single selected texture. And the texture of the clothing has transparent parts where the model would show the skin texture in Material Preview or Rendered. However the Solid mode does not take Mix Shader nodes etc. into account, so where the clothes texture is transparent, there the mesh will also be transparent and not show a different texture.


I don't really understand how of why that happened so this answer is only to hopefully get you back on track.

With Viewport Shading set to Solid,
open the Viewport Shading menu
and change the Color type to Material.



Now to view the Material textures on the model change the Viewport Shading to Material Preview mode.


